# Add XElements to exists xml file

Tags: c#, xmlreader, xmlwriter

I need read XElements from xml and add new XElements to exists xml. Firs I get XElements from xml, after I want add newXElements to xElements and update exists xml file. Then I call XmlWriter I have a Exception: "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process". Where is error? How append XElements to xml in stream?

```
IEnumerable<XElement> newXElements = GetNewXElements();
IEnumerable<XElement> xElements = GetXElements(path, "MyElement");

                using (XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create(path, settings))
                {
// Write to xml code

}


 public static IEnumerable<XElement> GetXElements(string inputUrl, string elementName)
        {
            using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(inputUrl))
            {
                reader.MoveToContent();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
                    {
                        if (reader.Name == elementName)
                        {
                            XElement el = XNode.ReadFrom(reader) as XElement;
                            if (el != null)
                            {
                                yield return el;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

XElement has it's own load method, just as it has it's own Save

```
    XElement q = XElement.Load(path);
    q.save(Path);
```

I'd recommend trying those out as an alternative to streamreading/writing to XElement.

In regards to your error, have you stepped through the code and identified where it's failing?

Comment: DavidFletcher, I used streamreading/writing because my xml file over 1 GB